# boto3 - Unable to use DynamoDB Global Tables version 2019.11.21

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am using the current version of boto3.
I was wondering is it possible to create global tables in DynamoDB that are of version 2019.11.21?
According to the boto3 documentation - https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.create_global_table - `This operation only applies to Version 2017.11.29 of global tables.`

Has anyone overcome this in boto3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the create_global_tables methods - I used the create_table and update_table method after posting a similar question on the boto3 issue board - https://github.com/boto/boto3/discussions/3293#discussioncomment-2901429

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CDK

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/aws-dynamodb-readme.html#amazon-dynamodb-global-tables

```
const globalTable = new dynamodb.Table(this, 'Table', {
  partitionKey: { name: 'id', type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING },
  replicationRegions: ['us-east-1', 'us-east-2', 'us-west-2'],
  billingMode: dynamodb.BillingMode.PROVISIONED,
});
```

Comment: CDK does not seem to let you specify the version from looking at the docs unfortunately

Comment: Why do you need to specify? You want v2 (2019), right? And that’s what it will deliver, right?

Comment: Some aws regions do not support the old version when creating global tables. The only approach I have seen so far is to update via the UI but its a process I am keen to automate

Comment: You don’t want 2017 GT, so why do you care if some regions don’t support (and never supported) the legacy version?

Comment: I want to deploy in some of the regions that don't support it. Hence looking for the 2019 version support

Comment: The CDK sets up the 2019 version. Use it and you get exactly what you say you want, right?